# How to include image's alternative text with textContent?

Tags: javascript, image, sorting, html-table

I have copy&pasted this nice little JavaScript table sorter script:

https://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/eYJYRyG

Now I'd like to also make columns sortable by alternative texts of images.

AFAIK the `textContent` method of JavaScript is used to read a cell's content:

```
a.cells[col].textContent.trim().localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
```

Is there a way to easily include an image's `alt` attribute here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to easily include an image's alt attribute here?

Yes, but not with `textContent`. You'd use `querySelector`:

```js
a.cells[col].querySelector("img").alt.localeCompare(b.cells[col].querySelector("img").alt)
```

Note that that code assumes:

1. That there **is** an `img` within the cell, and
2. That it's the *first* image whose `alt` you want

If #1 isn't true, you probably want to give yourself a utility function and use that:

```js
function getAlt(img) {
    return img ? img.alt : "";
}
```

Or if you can rely on **really** new features being present in the environment where the code runs, you could use the optional chaining operator that's new in ES2020:

```js
// ?. is new in ES2020
a.cells[col].querySelector("img")?.alt?.localeCompare(b.cells[col].querySelector("img")?.alt)
```

If #2 isn't true, `querySelector` accepts a full CSS selector so you can add any classes, etc., that may be necessary to narrow the search down.